# PostgreSQL 9.6: Update on a single row table takes an unreasonable amount of time

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, query-performance

I've got a table called `source` which has a primary key on its `id` and a “Unique Constraint” on the column `name`.

This is the way the table looks:

```
id                         int4
name                       varchar
last_updated_from_source   timestampz
last_graph_update_job_time timestampz
active                     bool
source_data                jsonb
```

This table effectively has a **single** row. That's all it has. The other tables in the database are way bigger (the biggest one has ~100M rows), but this one is not related in any way to the other ones.

When I run the following query:

```
update "source" set source_data = '{"seq": 1}' where "name" = 'abc';
```

It takes about 3 minutes to complete, which sounds absolutely insane for a table with a single row inside it. I ran `explain analyze` on it, with the resulting query:

```
explain analyze update "source" set source_data = '{"seq": 1}' where "name" = 'abc';
```

And the result:

```
Update on source  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=91) (actual time=158007.882..158007.882 rows=0 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on source  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=91) (actual time=0.023..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((name)::text = 'abc'::text)
Planning time: 0.208 ms
Execution time: 158007.953 ms
```

This database is currently residing on Google Cloud Platform. Interestingly enough, when I run this on a local PostgreSQL database (with the same schema and indices, foreign keys, etcetera), it doesn't take this long and behaves as expected. On GCP, it takes the CPU up to 40%.

I'm honestly baffled as to how it can take so long on GCP. Is there something I may be missing?

Let me know if there's anything else that might help explain this behavior.

edit: here are the locks

```
relation    16407   16614                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16607                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16600                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16591                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16589                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16582                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16578                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16576                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16569                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16565                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16565                               4/158336    240154  RowExclusiveLock    true    true
relation    16407   16563                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16563                               4/158336    240154  RowExclusiveLock    true    true
relation    16407   16556                               4/158336    240154  AccessShareLock true    true
relation    16407   16556                               4/158336    240154  RowExclusiveLock    true    true
virtualxid                  4/158336                    4/158336    240154  ExclusiveLock   true    true
relation    16407   11695                               5/532161    241496  AccessShareLock true    true
virtualxid                  5/532161                    5/532161    241496  ExclusiveLock   true    true
relation    16407   16565                               8/207258    241601  RowExclusiveLock    true    true
relation    16407   16563                               8/207258    241601  RowExclusiveLock    true    true
relation    16407   16556                               8/207258    241601  RowExclusiveLock    true    true
virtualxid                  8/207258                    8/207258    241601  ExclusiveLock   true    true
transactionid                       2264338             4/158336    240154  ExclusiveLock   true    false
transactionid                       2264338             8/207258    241601  ShareLock   false   false
tuple   16407   16556   0   47                      8/207258    241601  ExclusiveLock   true    false
transactionid                       2264534             8/207258    241601  ExclusiveLock   true    false
```

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible reasons:

1. A concurrent transaction is holding a lock on the row or the table that conflicts with your `UPDATE`.

   You can find that by querying `pg_locks` and looking whether your hanging backend has a row with `granted = FALSE`.
2. There are foreign keys that point to the table that are not indexed, and verifying the foreign key constraint takes a long time.

Option 2. can be ruled out because

- It would show in the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output.
- It would require that `source_data` had a `UNIQUE` constraint that is referenced by these foreign keys, which sounds unlikely.

So what remains are locks.

Your `pg_locks` output tells me that:

- The session with backend process id 241601 wants to lock the row in table 16556.
- This lock is currently held by transaction 2264338 (backend process id 240154).

So is you want the update to be faster, make sure that no concurrent transaction holds the lock for a longer time.

Comment: Done. I added the contents of pg_locks. What I've just noticed is that it's not really this table that's creating the issue, but some underlying operations that occur within the same procedure, and these happen with the really big tables.

Comment: You're quite right. I found out that the real problem was a `select` that was happening on the really big table (100M rows). By adding an index to it it seems to have solved it, but thanks to your insights I've been able to deduce this. Thank you very much Laurenz!